# Working with Partial Views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, view, partial-views

**Background**

I'm receiving the following error when trying to render a partial view in ASP.NET MVC. I am new to ASP.NET MVC and am sure the error is simple to resolve and just stems from my lack of complete understanding.

**Question** (*for those not wanting to read everything*):

What is causing this error ?

> Exception Details:
>   `System.InvalidOperationException`:
>   The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   `'MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel'`
>   but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel]'`.

---

**Entites**

I have two entities with a parent/child relationship.

```
Classroom                   StickyNote 
------------                -----------
Id          1 -----         Id
Name               \        Name
(...)               \       Content
                     ---- * ClassroomID
```

**Model**

In the `Model` the StickyNote Content is kept in a different table, and accessed (using `Linq-to-SQL` through the following method:

```
public IQueryable<StickyNote> GetStickyNotesByClassroom(Classroom classroom)
{
     return from stickynote in db.StickyNotes
            where stickynote.ClassroomID == classroom.ID
            select stickynote;
}
```

**Error**

I've created a partial view for displaying `StickyNote` content since it 'belongs' to the classroom it's on.  The problem I'm running into is that I'm not able to get it to display, and receive the following error:

> The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type:
>   `'MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel'`
>   but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel]'`.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   `System.InvalidOperationException`:
>   The model item passed into the
>   dictionary is of type
>   `'MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel'`
>   but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel]'`.

**Partial View**

Here is the partial view code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="
System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel>>" %>

    <table background="../../images/corkboard.jpg">

    <% foreach (var items in Model) { %>

        <tr>
        <% foreach (var item in items.StickyNotes) { %>
            <td><div class="sticky_note_container">

<!-- actually use a post it note here on the page -->
<div class="sticky_note">
<div class="sticky_note_content">
<!-- content of sticky note here -->
<% Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "ShowStickyNoteContent"); %>
<!-- end of content of sticky note -->
</div>
</div>
<div class="sticky_note_footer">&nbsp;</div>
<br clear="all" />
</div>
         </td>
      <% } %>
     </tr>
   <% } %>
</table>
```

**Parent View**

And the code from the other View that calls it:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits=
"System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel>" %>
{...}
  <% 
     Html.RenderPartial("StickyNotes", Model);
  %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing in a single instance of your ClassroomFormViewModel into and the View is  expecting a a collection i.e. `IEnumerable<ClassroomFormViewModel>.`

Change your declaration in your PartialView to

```
Inherits="
System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel>"
```

OR

What you really want (after really looking at your code) IS an `IEnumerable<ClassroomFormViewModel>`

so your Model in your calling page needs to be of `IEnumerable<ClassroomFormViewModel>`

Essentially you're trying to do this

```
public void Render(ClassroomFormViewModel model)
{
    RenderPartial(model) //Cannot cast single instance into an IEnumerable
}
public string RenderPartial(IEnumerable<ClassroomFormViewModel> model)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your partial should start

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="
System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyApp.Models.ClassroomFormViewModel>" >
```

I guess you want to display one classroom on you page.
If you want to display more then dont use a list of viewmodels.
Use one viewmodel that has a list of classrooms